# Fit normal distribution to weighted list

Tags: python, scipy

I have a bunch of data points, and I would like to fit a Normal distribution to the data. I see that scipy has the `stats.norm.fit` method, but this requires a single list of data points. Something like

```
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

whereas my data is contained in two lists, something like.

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
counts = [4, 3, 6, 1, 3]
```

How can I fit a normal distribution to data formatted in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could expand the values to the full set with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), and use `scipy.stats.norm.fit`:

```
In [54]: import numpy as np

In [55]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [56]: values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [57]: counts = [4, 3, 6, 1, 3]

In [58]: full_values = np.repeat(values, counts)

In [59]: full_values
Out[59]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])

In [60]: norm.fit(full_values)  # Estimate mean and std. dev.
Out[60]: (2.7647058823529411, 1.3516617991854185)
```

`scipy.stats.norm.fit` computes the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters.  For the normal distribution, these are just the sample mean and the square root of the (biased) sample variance.
As far as I know, the only relevant weighted statistical function in numpy or scipy is `numpy.average`.  You can do the computation yourself with `numpy.average`, using `counts` as the `weights` argument.

```
In [62]: sample_mean = np.average(values, weights=counts)

In [63]: sample_mean
Out[63]: 2.7647058823529411

In [64]: sample_var = np.average((values - sample_mean)**2, weights=counts)

In [65]: sample_var
Out[65]: 1.8269896193771626

In [66]: sample_std = np.sqrt(sample_var)

In [67]: sample_std
Out[67]: 1.3516617991854185
```

Note that `statistics.stdev` is based on the *unbiased* sample variance.  If that's what you want, you can adjust the scaling by multiplying the biased sample variance by `sum(counts)/(sum(counts) - 1)`:

```
In [79]: n = sum(counts)

In [80]: sample_var = n/(n-1)*np.average((values - sample_mean)**2, weights=counts)

In [81]: sample_var
Out[81]: 1.9411764705882353

In [82]: sample_std = np.sqrt(sample_var)

In [83]: sample_std
Out[83]: 1.3932610920384718
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way of characterising a sample from a (purported) normal population is to take its mean and standard deviation. We can use the built-in library to do that, along with [Martelli's lambda to flatten the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/131187).

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> counts = [4, 3, 6, 1, 3]
>>> import statistics
>>> sample = [c*[v] for (c, v) in zip(counts, values)]
>>> sample
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4], [5, 5, 5]]
>>> flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
>>> sample = flatten(sample)
>>> sample
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
>>> statistics.mean(sample)
2.764705882352941
>>> statistics.stdev(sample)
1.3932610920384718
```

Comment: @DanielStandage With the mean and standard deviation you can then recreate the Normal Distribution with its probability density function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: @KDecker: Exactly! With the mean and standard deviation you know *everything*.