# Fit normal distribution to weighted data with floats

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to fit some data points to a normal distribution, but I can't find a function that lets me put in the weights of the data points. `scipy.stats.norm.fit` only wants some data and if necessary the `loc` and `scale` parameters are used for average and standard deviation.

The weights of my data are floating points, so I can't use the solution described in [Fit normal distribution to weighted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440513/fit-normal-distribution-to-weighted-list) for obvious reasons.

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 44, 52]
weights = [0.06537925227866273, 0.9735569357920033, 3.1333312174908325, 5.558819116316957, ..., 0.0070813375592937555, 0.040237487324237445]
```

For me it's not a good solution to multiple the weights by 100 and then use `round()`, because the weights can get smaller than that.

Comment: Do you want to "fit some data points to a normal distribution", or fit parameters of a normal distribution to data points? Have you tried [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)?

Comment: Indeed, I have data points, and I want to fit a normal distribution to it.
I haven't tried scipy.optimize.minimize, I'm not sure how to use it:
Do I have to implement a function that uses Chi-square, 2 parameters (avg and stdev) and my values and weights as fixed arguments?

Comment: Your function should have 2 fitted parameters (mean & sigma). Your `values` and `weights` must also be passed. The function calculates probability for `values` and returns a diagnostic how well these match the normalized `weights`. This diagnostic can be chi2.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit the weighted data with a normal distribution by taking weighted averages over the data and the squared errors:

```
def fit_normal(values, weights):
    
    # prepare
    values = np.array(values)
    weights = np.array(weights)
        
    # estimate mean
    weights_sum =  weights.sum()
    mean = (values*weights).sum() / weights_sum
   
    # estimate variance
    errors = (values-mean)**2
    variance = (errors*weights).sum() / weights_sum
        
    return (mean, variance)
```